# How do I convert a string to a function reference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, function, reflection, reference

What I want is to pass a function's name as a string and have that be as if I passed a reference to the function. For example, I want to make this:

```
var test = function(fn){
  fn();
}
test(alert);
```

Equal to this:

```
var test = function(function_as_string){
    //...code that converts function_as_string to function reference fn
    fn();
}
test('alert');
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the function reference from the window object:

```
var fn = window[function_as_string];
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/nA6gU/

Comment: If the function was not a global function, let's say for example it was in the test function I could use `test[function_as_string]` just as well?

Comment: @Aust: If a function is declared inside another function, then it's local so it only exists while that function is running, so you can't get it at all from outside the function.

Comment: var fn = window[alert];
fn("yes"); result: TypeError: fn is not a function on FF 15

Comment: @GungFoo: Try `window['alert']`.

Comment: yeah.. that's the reference to the function, but how do i actually call it?

Comment: @GungFoo: Just like you did: `var fn = window['alert']; fn("yes");`.

Answer (score 3):

Functions are properties on an object. You can access them like any property and then use () to execute them.

```
​var o = {};
​​​​
o.b = function b() {
    alert("b");
}

o.b();

o["b"]();
```

If its a global function then its a property on window.

```
function a() {
    alert("a");
}

a();

window.a();

window["a"]();
```

In terms of your nested question, the best approach is to assign it as a property to an object that you will have access to later. For example:

```
function assignInside() {
    o.inside = function() {
        alert("inside");
    }
}

assignInside();
o["inside"]();
```

Here it all is as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/studgeek/eLfxh/).

PS, There is no reason to use eval in this case and lots of good reasons to avoid eval in general.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `eval()` function, it will let you supply a string that is evaluated as javascript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

```
var test = function(fn){
  eval(fn + "()");
}
test(alert);
```

Notes on eval from MDN:

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the
>   scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks
>   in ways of which the similar Function is not susceptible.
>
> eval() is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to
>   invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized
>   by modern JS engines.
>
> There are safe (and fast!) alternatives to eval() for common
>   use-cases.

look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: I've heard eval is bad to use. Would it be bad in this case?

Comment: If you are not using user input and hand it to the eval function i don't see why. Besides.. an evil user can always use the browsers console to inject code anyways. javascript is client-side and client-side security doesn't exist. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use eval to get a reference to the function -

```
var Namespace = {
    quack: function () {console.log('quack!')}
};

function test (fnName) {
    var fn = eval(fnName);
    fn();
}
test('Namespace.quack')
```

This could potentially allow you to pass other arguments in if you wanted to.

Oh, and the reason that you may not be able to simply use window[fnName] is if it's something like $.ajax - window['$.ajax'] will give you undefined.. so unless you want to create a complex function for looking up whether or not it's in another namespace, eval is your best bet.

Comment: As I just commented to @GungFoo, I've heard that using eval is bad. Is it bad in this case?

Comment: eval is like dynamite - its potentially dangerous if used for the wrong thing. However, like dynamite, it certainly has its uses - this would be one of them.

Comment: it seems to also be slow.. :o

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var fn = new Function(function_as_string)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to make a new function. I'm trying to call a function that already exists.

Comment: Then why are you passing that as string? Functions are first class so you can just pass the function around as a callback for example

Comment: I have no choice but to pass it as a string unfortunately.